# How to "Load" or "Get" a domain in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

In nhibernate you can use "Load" or "Get" to take an "Id" and load it into a domain model. How do you do something like that in EF?

I have some "Ids" that I am sending from the client to my server. I want take the new item and associate them with the new item without having to actually getting them from the db.

In nhibernate I would do something like this

```
public void MyMethod(int brandId, string productName)
{
   Product p = new Product()
   {
        Name = productName,
        Brand = session.Load<Brand>(brandId)
   };

   session.Save(p);
   session.Commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Entity Framework I use Attribute Decoration on the Model

```
public class DbEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated()]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
}

public class Product : DbEntity
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public virtual Brand Brand {get;set;}
}

public class Brand : DbEntity
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

We use `virtual` for lazy loading, and depending on whether you want Cascade On Delete or not depends whether you put `Guid BrandId` there or not.

Look at my other question and answer to see what associations are all about:[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545977/code-first-entity-framework-virtual-and-foreign-key-confusions)

To get records and crud I have these classes:

- Context which inherits `DbContext` from System.Data.Entity (i think)
- Repository which uses an instantiates a Context
- IRepository which is ninjected

It's in the Repository where I have this save method:

```
public void SaveEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : DbEntity
{
   if (entity.Id.Equals(Guid.Empty))
      _context.Set<TENtity>().Add(entity);
   else
      _context.Entry(entity).State = Modified;

   _context.SaveChanges()
}

public void DeleteEntity<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : DbEntity
{
   _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);

   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This way, you can add as many entities and you only need one save and delete method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the version of Entity Framework that you're using.

In EF > 4, the concept of `FK Association` was added. This means that, if your entity has a property called `BrandId`, you can simply use that. See more information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx).

```
Product p = new Product()
{
    Name = productName,
    BrandId = brandId
};
```

If you're using Code First, you can define this property on your model along with the `Brand` property. See more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).

```
public class Product {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

If you're creating a model from a database, you can set an option to preserve the ID properties in the designer.

In EF < 4, you have to create an entity key based on the value. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425081/entity-framework-how-to-set-association-value) for more information.

```
Product p = new Product() {
    Name = productName
};
p.BrandReference.EntityKey = new EntityKey("MyEntities.Brand", "BrandId", brandId);
```

Comment: I am using Ef 6..I do have BrandId in my codefirst but how about in situations of Many? Say for some reason a product has many brands. How does it work then?

Comment: @chobo2 - In the case of a Many relationship, I believe you can create a new instance of `Brand`, set its `Id` property, and add it to the `Brands` collection of the new `Product`. I haven't tested that, though.

Comment: @chobo2 If you look at my answer, there is a link to show how associations work....